# How do I access beanstalk application venv?

Tags: amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-s3, nlp, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

this last week I have been trying to upload a flask app using AWS Beanstalk.

The main problem for me was loading a very heavy library as part of the bundle (there is a 500mb limit for uploading the bundle code).
Instead, I tried to use requirements.txt file so it would download the library directly to the server.
Unfortunately, every time I tried to include the library name in the requirements file, it failed to load it (torch library).

on pythonanywhere server there is a console which allows you to access the virtual environment and simply type

> pip install torch

which was very useful and comfortable.
I am looking for something similar in AWS beanstalk, so that I could install the library directly instead of relying on the requirements.txt file.

I have been at it for a few days now and can't make any progress.
your help would be much appreciated.

another question,
is it possible to load the venv to Amazon-S3 and then access the folder from the beanstalk environment?

Comment: I managed to open a console, but couldn't do much on it. I tried to connect it to my instance and after "succeeding" couldn't gain permission to install anything.

Answer (score 1):

Its **not a good practice** to "manually" install your dependencies or configure your EB env from inside. This is only useful for testing and debugging purposes. Thus keep that it mind.

To get your venv, you have to ssh to your EB instance using regular `ssh` or **web-based clients** available in AWS EC2 console when you locate your EB EC2 instance. `Session manager` should work out-of-the-box to enable you to login to the instance.

When you login to the instance, then to `activate` your venv, you do:

```
# start bash
bash
# source venv
source /var/app/venv/staging-*/bin/activate
```

Comment: In my case I also needed to get a bunch of env variables from the eb configuration into my shell once I `eb ssh` in, to that end here is a gist that describes how to do this: https://gist.github.com/123epsilon/67f9d75a2c78a164a1cb6a1d40fe673f